# Flask-session TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

Flask keeps spitting out this error:

`TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'`.

Apparently the flask-session module is trying to compare session expire with current time. I tried setting the session expire to one day to avoid its value from being None, but it doesnt seem to work. If we get the session expire to be of set value, I think it might fix the problem.

[image: Error]

```
from flask import Flask
from pymongo import MongoClient
from flask_session import Session
import datetime
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from dashboard import dashboard
from auth import auth


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'xxxxx'
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'mongodb'
mongo = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://xxxxxxxxx')
app.config['SESSION_MONGODB'] = mongo
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] =  datetime.timedelta(days=5)
app.config['SESSION_MONGODB_DB'] = 'matjari'
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = True
Session(app)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
matjari = mongo.matjari
mongo_users = matjari['users']

app.register_blueprint(dashboard, url_prefix='/dashboard')
app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/auth')




@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'alive'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Weird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQAb0.png)

For some magical reason the issue seems to have resolved itself. I havent changed anything in my code. If you have any explanation please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the below line has something to do with the error going away.

```
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = True
```

If I make `SESSION_PERMEMNAT = True` it will not give the error, but not entirely sure about the reliability

**Update:**

Found this [issue](https://github.com/fengsp/flask-session/issues/67) on flask-session Github. Seems like it has something do with the database **sessions** table **expiry** column being empty.

Comment: i solved the issue by updating to the new module flask-sessionstore

Comment: That's great. It has the same structure and database right?